# Using calc to indent child element of CSS Grid accurately align with grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-calc

I have a content block within a CSS Grid item, which works fine. In some instances I want to be able to indent a child element 1 or 2 columns so accurately so it aligns to its parent grid.

I did achieve that by applying to same grid to the child block (`storyblock__caption` in example) however that led to elements spanning 100% wide of the available space, which I didn't want. So I decided to try and tackle it using `calc`.

I've included an example that at a glance actually looks correct. The paragraph in the example using `calc` appears to align to the 2nd column of the grid. However if you were to change the spacing so it aligned to the left edge of the 3rd column, something like: `margin-left: calc(((2 / 4) * 100%) - ((2 / 4) * 12px));` you can see the math doesn't add up.

I believe this is could be because the grid isn't taking into account the 12px left/right padding of `storyblock__caption`. But I've tried to add/subtract 24px from the calculation but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here's my example code as it stands:

```css
/* #BASE */

body  {color: white; margin: 0 auto;}
img   {width: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
h1    {margin-bottom: 15px;}
p     {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.btn  {background: white; color: black; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 24px; text-decoration: none;}

/* #CONTENT BLOCK */

.storyblock {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 375px;
}

.storyblock--overlay {
  align-items: end;
}

.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__media,
.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__caption {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.storyblock__media,
.storyblock__caption {
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.storyblock__caption {
  padding: 0 12px 24px;
}

.storyblock__caption p {
  margin-left: calc(((1 / 4) * 100%) - ((1 / 4) * 12px));
}
```

```html
<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variables and make your life easier. I have changed the gap to `10px` to better identify the valuee and avoid the confusion with the padding that has the same value. You can also use CSS variables for the padding and the gap

```css
/* #BASE */

body  {color: white; margin: 0 auto;}
img   {width: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
h1    {margin-bottom: 15px;}
p     {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.btn  {background: white; color: black; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 24px; text-decoration: none;}

/* #CONTENT BLOCK */

.storyblock {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 375px;
}

.storyblock--overlay {
  align-items: end;
}

.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__media,
.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__caption {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.storyblock__media,
.storyblock__caption {
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.storyblock__caption {
  padding: 0 12px 24px;
}

.storyblock__caption p.indent {
  margin-left: calc(var(--n)*(100% + 2*12px + 10px)/4 - 12px);
}
```

```html
<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>Default</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>1 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent" style="--n:1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>2 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent" style="--n:2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>3 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent" style="--n:3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks way more flexible/scalable. Even across other grids with more columns etc, just using the 1 `calc` in the CSS. I guess by math was right at least! But it looks like you've rearranged the sum so I don't need to change both values - which I needed to in my example! :)

Comment: So broken down is that calculation... `calc (Column Indent x (100% + 2 x Outer Padding With + Grid Gutter Width) / Amount of Columns - 12px)` ...whats the last 12px. I know it works just trying to think through it haha

Comment: @user1406440 it's also the padding ;) that's why I changed the gap to 10px so you can see both padding and gap value

Comment: That'd be why ha! I was thinking why is it just one value (12px) but I guess it's removing 12px multiplied by the var value?

Comment: @user1406440 we first add the padding inside the N*( .. ) to get back the full width of the grid and later we need to remove only the left padding because the margin will shift after the padding

Answer (score 0):

I'd appreciate a sanity check on it but I think I have resolved this by using the following calculation to indent by 1 column and align with parent grid gutters...

**1 col:** `margin-left: calc(((1 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((3 / 4) * 12px));`

Then if you wanted to indent by 2 columns you'd just change the fractions to:

**2 cols:** `margin-left: calc(((2 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((2 / 4) * 12px));`

And finally 3 columns. Which looks silly but just to complete the set...

**3 cols:** `margin-left: calc(((3 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((1 / 4) * 12px));`

...in future I might just set the same grid on the child container and wrap the items I don't want to stretch 100% wide in a div!

```css
/* #BASE */

body  {color: white; margin: 0 auto;}
img   {width: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
h1    {margin-bottom: 15px;}
p     {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.btn  {background: white; color: black; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 24px; text-decoration: none;}

/* #CONTENT BLOCK */

.storyblock {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 375px;
}

.storyblock--overlay {
  align-items: end;
}

.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__media,
.storyblock--overlay .storyblock__caption {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.storyblock__media,
.storyblock__caption {
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.storyblock__caption {
  padding: 0 12px 24px;
}

.storyblock__caption p.indent-1 {
  margin-left: calc(((1 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((3 / 4) * 12px));
}

.storyblock__caption p.indent-2 {
  margin-left: calc(((2 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((2 / 4) * 12px));
}

.storyblock__caption p.indent-3 {
  margin-left: calc(((3 / 4) * (100% + 24px)) - ((1 / 4) * 12px));
}
```

```html
<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>Default</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>1 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>2 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storyblock storyblock--overlay">
  <div class="storyblock__media">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/375/500" alt="ALT TEXT" />
  </div>
  <div class="storyblock__caption">
    <h1>3 Col Indent</h1>
    <p class="indent-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
    <a href=" #" class="btn">Shop Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```